# Defining base url constant instead of using base_url()?

Tags: codeigniter, constants, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, base-url

Instead of calling the function:

```
base_url()
```

for every single link, would it make sense to define your base url in constants.php:

```
define('BASE_URL', 'http://mysite.com/');
```

and then use that constant so that the function call isn't potentially made many multiple times on a page?

Answer (score 3):

Not entirely.  You'll run into unexpected behavior if you use any of the following functions:

- `redirect()`
- `site_url()`
- `base_url()`
- `form_open()`
- `anchor()`

That's not an exhaustive list--many other functions depend on the base url config setting.  A better approach might be to use relative links instead, rather than hard-coding absolute URLs.

I, myself, have been tempted to use `site_url()` to define every link as a measure of paranoia (wondering to myself whether the URL structure will ever change).  But really, undergoing a massive overhaul of the sitemap will create more difficult problems than just the links.  For the sake of development, I now just use relative links where it makes sense.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I wouldn't worry about multiple calls to `base_url()` - I doubt it will have a significant impact on performance.

Additionally, I dislike the idea of using a constant because the base URL will essentially be defined twice, in two different places. Once in `config.php` and once wherever the `BASE_URL` constant would live. However, that's just my thought on it - perhaps someone else could make the case for it.

**tl;dr** I don't think multiple calls to `base_url()` is a problem and, in most cases, probably won't have a significant impact on performance.

Comment: "Additionally, I dislike the idea of using a constant because the base URL will essentially be defined twice, in two different places. Once in config.php and once wherever the BASE_URL constant would live" .. You are absolutely right. So this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13825685/458204 could fix this problem.