# codeigniter base_url inside constants file

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Currently I display images in the following way:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url().USER_UPLOAD_URL.$post['userPhoto'] ?>" />
```

USER_UPLOAD_URL is defined inside application/config/constants.php.

```
define('USER_UPLOAD_URL', "uploads/user_uploads/");
```

Is there any way to include base_url() inside constants.php? In this way I wouldn't need to write each time base_url() inside view. Is there any alternative approach?

tnx

Answer (score 9):

constants.php loading before config.php, so you can't use `$config['base_url']` from constants.php.

But you can do something like that:

**constants.php**:

```
define('BASE_URL', "http://mysite.com");
define('USER_UPLOAD_URL', BASE_URL."uploads/user_uploads/");
```

**config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = BASE_URL;
```

Comment: This is really a great answer, it helped me a lot with this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/20445771/458204

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `base_url()` in the constants file because the constants file is loaded first, and the `base_url()` is only loaded when you either autoload the url helper, or load it per controller.

Here's a suggestion though, you could possibly define it in your controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    define('USER_UPLOAD_URL', base_url('uploads/user_uploads/'));
}
```

Which would then be accessible to the view.

Comment: I thought about something like that, but this would split constants around different parts of application.

Comment: @user1324762 Agreed it's not the best solution, just the first thing that popped into my head, maybe you could set something in the constants file, just without using the base_url() function

Answer (score 0):

I'd complement the @Dale answer making use of a custom controller. At first place, create the controller at /application/core/GeneralController.php:

```
<?php
class GeneralController extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        define('USER_UPLOAD_URL', base_url('uploads/user_uploads/'));
    }
}
```

Now, you can extends all controllers from `GeneralController` instead of CI_Controller, because `USER_UPLOAD_URL` is now defined

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question still i overcame this issue using `APPPATH`.
`APPPATH` works inside constants.php. but it returns path as `var/www/html/projectfolder/application` inside application folder you can store you data within a new folder or `third_party` folder. 
In constants you can define as eg `define('pace-min-js',APPPATH.'third_party/luna/vendor/pacejs/pace.min.js');`